# using like, or and join for searching data in jtablefield netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

How to use like ,or with join? for search

I already try but no avail

```
SELECT kd_barangkeluar,nm_barang,tgl_keluar,jml_keluar,nm_toko 
FROM toko JOIN barang_keluar USING (kd_toko) JOIN barang USING (kd_barang)";
```

And this my try

```
SELECT kd_barangkeluar like'"+search.getText+"', 
or nm_barang like'"+search.getText+"', 
or tgl_keluar like'"+search.getText+"', 
or jml_keluar, nm_toko like'" +search.getText + "' 
FROM toko JOIN barang_keluar USING (kd_toko) JOIN barang USING (kd_barang)";
```

The netbeans say there "no columns"

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: you tag this question `mysql` so i think you facing SQL related  problem ...
plz provide your DB table and sample data...